# Ion segment buttons are shown except the first one

Tags: html, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I have an ion-segment element with his ion-segment-button subelements, my idea is to make an horizontal scrollable menu to have the quantity of buttons that i want to put in that section.

In my case i'm using 5 buttons, 1 for each quarter (let's suppose this is a football match), also it has another button, the EX button, this button is for an Extra time (in case of other sports requires that extra time).

The problem is that i achieve to make ion-segment scrollable and see his elements (since 2th to last), but the first ion-segment-button is never shown! (i think the ion-segment is not taking the first element for some reason...).

In fact, i checked that all buttons have both width and height (and they are), so i think this is a bit strange...

HTML structure:

```
<ion-footer>
  <ion-segment color="tertiary" value = "primer-cuarto" class = "scrollable-segment">

    <ion-segment-button value = "primer-cuarto" (click) = "selectSection('primer-cuarto')">
      <ion-label>1er cuarto</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>

    <ion-segment-button value = "segundo-cuarto" (click) = "selectSection('segundo-cuarto')">
      <ion-label>2do cuarto</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>

    <ion-segment-button value = "tercer-cuarto" (click) = "selectSection('tercer-cuarto')">
      <ion-label>3er cuarto</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>

    <ion-segment-button value = "cuarto-cuarto" (click) = "selectSection('cuarto-cuarto')">
      <ion-label>4to cuarto</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>

    <ion-segment-button value = "cuarto-extra" (click) = "selectSection('cuarto-extra')">
      <ion-label>Ex</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>

</ion-footer>
```

some css styles:

```
ion-segment{

    background: gainsboro;

}

ion-segment-button ion-icon{

    color: #7044ff;

}

ion-segment-button ion-label{

    word-break: break-word;

}

.scrollable-segment{
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

this is what i'm obtaining having the scroll in 0 (full to the left):

[image]

as you see the first quarter is never shown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a scrollable property to ion-segment

eg.

```
<ion-segment (ionChange)="segmentChanged($event)" scrollable>
```

Refer: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment